# One shared material with different custom property for each object

Tags: materials, drivers, properties, procedural

I'm trying to procedurally generate a scene with several objects (cubes for now!) sharing a single material, but appearing and fading out at different times. So far, I have been able to place the objects and show them at the correct keyframes. See below for the current state of the scene.

[image: Several cubes, with keyframes controlling custom glow value]

Now I want to change their "glow" values independently of each other. If it's possible, I would like to use a custom `glow` property for each object, and have that drive a Value node in the material they share.

In other words, object `Cube` should set `glow = 1.0` at frame 0 and `glow = 0.0` at frame 5, `Cube.001` should set `glow = 1.0` at frame 14 and `glow = 0.0` at frame 19, etc. So the scene would show several cubes, all at different levels of glowing. That value would drive the `Value` node in the material tree for each object.

After reading through a lot of questions and answers on StackExchange, I learned that there isn't a material node that can read an object's custom property. I also tried setting up a Value node (like in the screenshot) and using a driver from a custom property, but it can only be driven by a single object at a time.

So is there some way to have multiple objects pass their own property to a single instance of a material? I'm not familiar enough with the data model to know if it is. Maybe the driver scripted expressions could work, but I can't find enough documentation on them to be sure.

I can clone the material once for every object if I absolutely have to, but I would definitely prefer defining it only once to keep the scene clean. I want to swap out the cubes for more interesting objects with multiple materials, so cloning materials will become harder.